# Como cambiar el ancho de las columnas(widht) con bootstrap 4

Tags: php, oracle, bootstrap-4

Buen día colegas.

Tengo un problema, el cliente quiere asignar el ancho de columnas predeterminado, con unos valores que ya vienen por defecto en la base de datos.
Ya estoy obteniendo el dato de los valores de los titulos. Y ya tengo la tabla impresa con php y bootstrap 4.

[image: ancho de columnas]

En esta imagen están los valores que recibirá cada ancho de la columna(estos valores pueden cambiar dependiendo de los valores que estén almacenados en la base de datos).

[image: Imagen donde se le aplicaron los anchos]

Y esta es la tabla donde se le aplicaran los anchos de columna.

Y este es mi codigo de como estoy imprimiendo las tablas con bootstrap

```
<h5><strong>CARACTERÍSTICAS TÉCNICAS</strong></h5>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-format table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                           <!-- en esta parte se imprimen los titulos -->
                                    <?php foreach ($arrayContenido2[1] as $contenido): ?>
                                    <th><?php echo $contenido ?></th>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                          <tr>
                        <?php 
                        $count = count($arrayContenido2);
                       //En esta parte se imprime el contenido de las tablas
                        for ($i=2; $i <$count ; $i++) {
                            foreach ($arrayContenido2[$i] as $key => $value) {
                            //si es el primer titulo lo ponga en negrita
                                if ($key == 'A') {
                                    echo "<th scope='row'>".$value."</th>";
                                }else{
                                    echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
                                }
                            }
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                        ?>              
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: ¿En que unidades de medida vienen los tamaños?

Comment: En centímetros es la unidad de medida :/

Comment: A ver si entiendo bien, quieres que las columnas de la tabla tengan el ancho que traes de la base de datos y que este ancho esté en **cm**?

Comment: Exacto, así es. ¿Tienes alguna idea :'(?

Comment: Si, puedes utilizar `cm` en css pero no es muy recomendado ya que la medida no siempre es exacta, y agregarle el ancho que te trae la base de datos al `th` así `<th style="width: <?php echo $ancho ?>cm">`

Comment: Y eso lo puedo hacer en una escala de 100% por ejemplo que toda mi tabla valga 100% e irle asignando a las columnas como lo mencionaste anteriormente aunque no sean cm. El cliente nada más quiere ver que si se dimensionan las columnas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si necesitas que cada `th` tenga un ancho con respecto al número que te trae la base de datos y un ancho total de 100% podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
$cabeceras = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'uno',
        'width' => 3
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'dos',
        'width' => 5
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'tres',
        'width' => 2
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'cuatro',
        'width' => 7
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'cinco',
        'width' => 4
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'seis',
        'width' => 8
    ),
);

// Sacamos el total de todos los width
$anchoTotal = array_sum(array_column($cabeceras, 'width'));
```

Y en tu table puedes ir declarando el ancho de cada `th` con respecto al total

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ($cabeceras as $cabecera): ?>
                    <?php
                    // Calculamos el ancho con respecto al 100%
                    $width = ($cabecera['width'] * 100)/$anchoTotal;
                    ?>
                    <th style="width: <?php echo $width ?>%">
                        <?php echo $cabecera['name'] ?>
                    </th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Obtendremos algo así (puse los colores para diferenciar las columnas):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 10.344827586207%; background-color: #8ac8b6">
          uno </th>
        <th style="width: 17.241379310345%; background-color: #64bf64">
          dos </th>
        <th style="width: 6.8965517241379%; background-color: #13d229">
          tres </th>
        <th style="width: 24.137931034483%; background-color: #708928">
          cuatro </th>
        <th style="width: 13.793103448276%; background-color: #678121">
          cinco </th>
        <th style="width: 27.586206896552%; background-color: #d7ed7a">
          seis </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Justo lo que estaba buscando muchísimas gracias.